# Olympic Games - when referred to as Games or games

Tags: capitalization

Katherine Grainger is Britain’s most decorated female Olympic athlete and the first British woman to win medals at five successive **G**ames.

OR

Katherine Grainger is Britain’s most decorated female Olympic athlete and the first British woman to win medals at five successive **g**ames.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The word "games" is standing in for the name of an event (Olympic Games), and is capitalized accordingly.

[Associated Press](https://www.ap.org/press-releases/2012/ap-compiles-editorial-style-guide-for-summer-games) issued a style guide in 2012, which included the following:

> ***Olympics or Olympic Games***
>
> *Always capitalized. There are Summer Olympics and Winter Olympics, or Summer Games and Winter Games.*

See also: the [ESL Library blog entry](http://blog.esllibrary.com/2014/02/06/grammar-rules-for-the-olympics/) on Olympic grammar, which includes:

> *The Olympics, being an event name, is always capitalized. Words associated with the actual name of the Olympics are also capitalized (Winter, Sochi, Games), but other related words are not (medal, podium, torch).*